# How to apply external CSS stylesheet to document in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-office, css, microsoft-word, styles

Seems like there should be a simple answer here, but can't find it in Word Help, MS Office Online, or Google...

I simply want to be able to apply an external CSS stylesheet (*standardstyles.css*, e.g.) to the current document in Microsoft Word (2007). I've pored over the Styles menu, looked in all the classic formatting dialogs, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

Save your Word document as `'Web page (*.htm; *.html)'`. This will give you a html document with an associated folder named after the document (e.g. Doc1.htm and Doc1_files).

Add your stylesheet to the folder and then link to it using:

`'Developer' tab > Document Template > Linked CSS (tab) > Add...'`

The css heading styles (`h1`, `h2` etc.) in the stylesheet correspond to the heading styles applied within Word and the `p` style corresponds to the Word 'Normal' style. Similarly for lists and tables etc.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember seeing this before. Sounds like what I'm looking for, but when I select a .CSS file, it doesn't update the current document (whether importing or linking), and the linked stylesheet disappears after saving & reloading the .DOCX document. Ideas?

Comment: You need to save as a web page first. You can't apply a css stylesheet to a .docx file directly as it's not html.

Comment: This is awesome! I didn't even know this was an option, and now I have complete control over the appearance of the saved HTML. This still works in Word 2013, BTW.